# Is there a dql command to find out the docbase owner name?

Tags: documentum

Alternatively is there a way to specify what user is used to execute a dm_job?

Comment: select * from dm_user where user_group_name = 'docu' returns a few possibilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DQL to get install owner
select r_install_owner from dm_server_config

In Job properties, check "Pass standard arguments", and the launch user will be passed to the Jobs method. For example see Job dm_GwmTask_Alert and its file 
$DM_HOME$\bin\dm_gwm_jobs.ebs

Answer (score 0):

To answer the initial question "Is there a dql command to find out the docbase owner name?"

To find out the docbase owner name:

```
select * from dm_user where user_name='dm_dbo'
```